# Websphere 9.0.0.7 - Cluster Loading Wrong JPA Specification

Tags: jpa, websphere, persistence

Having a very frustrating problem right now that I've exhausted all other avenues of research on. In short, we have a certain vendor application that runs on Websphere 9 and requires JPA 2.0 specification for java persistence.

The issue is, despite setting the JPA specification level to 2.0 in the administrative console, as well as setting it via wsadmin command directly, the cluster continues to load JPA 2.1 and ultimately causing big errors when the application runs.

We see it in the startup logs at:

> 00000001 SharedJPAComp I   CWWJP0048I: Initialized the JPA service for
>   the JPA 2.1 specification level.

Seen in verbose class loading at:

> class load: com.ibm.ws.jpa.runtime.JPA21Runtime from:
>   file:/opt/app/WebSphere90/AppServer_x64/plugins/com.ibm.ws.jpa.container21.jar

And seen in System.Out logs during the actual exception :

> 0000017c BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "insert" on bean
>   "BeanId([app name redacted], null)". Exception data:
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/persistence/EntityManager;
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jpa.runtime.JPA21Runtime.createEntityManagerInstance(JPA21Runtime.java:165)

Actual correct setting shown here
[Websphere Java Persistence Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB1C0.png)

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue? Research so far has found nothing. Running on Websphere fixpack 9.0.0.7

Comment: WebSphere uses an internal OSGi bundle selection mechanism to choose its JPA provider.  It's based on a descriptor in the profile's servers/(servername)/configuration/wsBundleMetaData directory.  If you check that location, you should see jpa-2.0.xml but NOT jpa-2.1.xml.  If they're both present, delete the 2.1 version; if they're both missing, try reconfiguring the setting and see if that puts the right version in place.  If the right one is in place but it's still not working, then you probably need to open a support ticket, because any more debug is going to require trace analysis.

Comment: Yeah, for the cluster in question only jpa-2.0.xml is present. The nodeagent that the cluster is running on has jpa-2.1.xml , but I assume that shouldn't have an affect. We do have a ticket open, which will probably be what is required unfortunately.